# write unit test for event handlers that updates some state in react using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write some unit tests for the event handlers that I wrote inside my component. I would like to write tests for the states updates inside that event handlers.
For example I have the following function that are called onMouseDown inside the component. How can I write some tests about that.

```
const [visible, setVisibility ] = useState(false);

  const onSelection = () => {
    setVisibility(!visible)
 };

<div onMouseDown ={()=> onSelection(items)}>Click</div>
{visible && <div>simple text</div>}
```

Can anybody guide me through there. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide complete, minimal code. How do you declare and use the `visible` state

Comment: Hey, edited the code where I have declared the visible state using useState

Comment: How did you use it?

Comment: Is it enough now. Just display a div when visible is true inside the component render function

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the component like this:

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Example() {
  const [visible, setVisibility] = useState(false);

  const onSelection = () => {
    setVisibility(!visible);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onMouseDown={() => onSelection()}>Click</div>
      {visible && <div>simple text</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

We test the behavior of the component from the user's perspective.

We should test: What is the component rendering before triggering the `mousedown` event and what is rendered after the `visible` state changes.

`index.test.tsx`

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Example from './';

describe('70577146', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Example />);
    const button = wrapper.find('div[children="Click"]');
    expect(wrapper.find('div[children="simple text"]').exists()).toBeFalsy();
    button.simulate('mousedown');
    expect(wrapper.find('div[children="simple text"]').exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70577146/index.test.tsx (11.966 s)
  70577146
    ✓ should pass (11 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.599 s, estimated 14 s
```

Comment: but it doesn't check for the setVisibilty states what if we have multiple updates inside the onSelection ( setVisibility, setItems etc)

Comment: @saon When you trigger the event, the event handler will call `setVisibilty`, you don't need to assert `setVisibilty` is called or not.  Which means you shouldn't test the implementation detail. You should test the component behavior. If you have multiple updates, you should test the output of the component with different states. Your question didn't have complete component code. How do I know there are multiple updates, and I'm just giving tests based on the code you're giving.

Comment: Okay but is there anyways, just to test the onSelection method without even targeting the dom element?